# JSF Primefaces panelgrid border

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to remove the border from the panelgrid but not from the subcomponents for example the panel:

```
<p:panelGrid cols="2" styleClass="ui-noborder">
<p:panel>Test</p:panel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

But the problem is that Test panel also has no border - is there a style class ui-border? I could not find anything on that.

Comment: Can you just add a style on the p:panel like style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;"

Comment: yes I know that I could do that but I was hoping that there was another way